# how to create files in grunt without change its name (responsive images)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, responsive

i'm creating responsive images with grunt but i don't want changing its name

my code :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    responsive_images: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                sizes: [{
                    suffix: "",
                    width: 800,
                    quality: 50
                }]
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
                cwd: 'img/',
                dest: 'img/large/'
            }]
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['responsive_images']);
};
```

and i receive output :

img/large/1-800.jpg

but i want :

img/large/1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `options` object of your `responsive_images` task add the following two [options](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images#options):

- `name`
- `rename`

Set the values of both properties (i.e. options) to `false`. For example:

```js
// ...
options: {
  name: false,   // <-- Add this
  rename: false, // <-- Add this
  sizes: [{
    suffix: "",
    width: 800,
    quality: 50
  }]
},
// ...
```